# angularjs play audio from a link from firebase

Tags: angularjs, html, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm facing a problem to load a html5 media player to play audio (OGG) file from a link firebase.

Here's my view

```
<my-audio>
    <audio>
        <source id="lol" ng-src="{{msg.text}}" />
    </audio>
    <button class="play">Play Music</button>
    <button class="pause">Pause Music</button>   
</my-audio>
```

Here's my directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('myAudio', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var player = element.children('.player')[0];
            element.children('.play').on('click', function() {

                player.play();

            });
            element.children('.pause').on('click', function() {
                player.pause();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

{{msg.text}} comes from a firebase link, example:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/smartdev-8a133.appspot.com/o/whatsapp_media_audios%2F08CB2B0764907A3300.ogg?alt=media&token=a1b80178-2309-4ea3-b22f-b6d6aa52efd9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on how you select the elements by class, according to [angular.element docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), `.children()` doesn't support selector, therefore you have to select them in a different way.

For example:

```
var $playBtn = angular.element(element[0].getElementsByClassName('play'));
```

I've made an example using a static `Audio` object to exemplify:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('myAudio', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {

        // Using a static Audio object 
        var player = new Audio('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/smartdev-8a133.appspot.com/o/whatsapp_media_audios%2F08CB2B0764907A3300.ogg?alt=media&token=a1b80178-2309-4ea3-b22f-b6d6aa52efd9');
        
        var elm = element[0],
          byClass = function(klass) {
            return angular.element(elm.getElementsByClassName(klass));
          };

        byClass('play')
          .on('click', function() {

            player.play();

          });
        byClass('pause')
          .on('click', function() {
            player.pause();
          });
      }
    };
  });

angular.element(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

```html
<my-audio>
  <button class="play">Play Music</button>
  <button class="pause">Pause Music</button>
</my-audio>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE** Added example using html `<audio> tag`.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('myAudio', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {            
        
        // Using html <audio> tag with controlls
        var player = element.find('audio')[0];
        
        var elm = element[0],
          byClass = function(klass) {
            return angular.element(elm.getElementsByClassName(klass));
          };

        byClass('play')
          .on('click', function() {

            player.play();

          });
        byClass('pause')
          .on('click', function() {
            player.pause();
          });
      }
    };
  });

angular.element(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

```html
<my-audio>
  <audio src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/smartdev-8a133.appspot.com/o/whatsapp_media_audios%2F08CB2B0764907A3300.ogg?alt=media&token=a1b80178-2309-4ea3-b22f-b6d6aa52efd9" controls></audio>
  <button class="play">Play Music</button>
  <button class="pause">Pause Music</button>
</my-audio>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: cool it's working now thanks! now its possible to show the html5-audio tag progress bar and volume in html?

Comment: Well, you can use the native `HTMLAudioElement` using the `<audio>` tag. You can play and pause as you can do with the static `Audio` object, but it'll use the browser's native player, it means each browser has a different player (if so), if it's a problem for you you can find out an angularjs audio player.

Comment: @sealabr I've updated my answer to use the audio element (and commented the static Audio object way), have a look and see if it helps.